# If condition error?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have made a condition that if variable is null. But still this code breaks the app because of null variable.

CODE:

```
var page = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage"];
var hash = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Ayath"];
if (page == null && hash == null)
// or if i use if (page == null || hash == null)
{    
MessageBox.Show("No Bookmark has been saved !");
}
else
{
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/myWeb.xaml?Page=" + page + "&id=" + hash, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: You should put a breakpoint, launch your app in debug and look at which variable is null.

Comment: Does it breaks at var page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage"];` is returning null or any value. try this.

```
 object pagedata = null,hashdata = null;
if(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("qsPage") && IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Ayath"))
{
  var page = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage"];
  var hash = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Ayath"];

  pagedata = page;
  hashdata = hash;
}
 if (pagedata == null && hashdata == null)
// or if i use if (page == null || hash == null)
{    
 MessageBox.Show("No Bookmark has been saved !");
}
else
{
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/myWeb.xaml?Page=" + pagedata + "&id=" + hashdata, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Error: `The qsPage and Ayath doesn't in the current context`

Comment: now the app doesn't breaks. But, `MessageBox.Show("No Bookmark has been saved !");` hasn't run

Comment: Yes because if IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("qsPage")  doesn't contain any value then it will not execute the code inside the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Using `&&` in the if condition, the page can be null but the hash no, so it go to the else clausule and, as the page is null, it fail.

Try replacing `&&` for `||` This way, everytime page OR hash is null, it show the message box.

Updated: As the page and hash variables are string, you need to test them using String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, This way:

```
var page = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["qsPage"];
var hash = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Ayath"];
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(page.ToString()) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hash.ToString()))
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Bookmark has been saved !");
}
else
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/myWeb.xaml?Page=" + page + "&id=" + hash, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: What types page and hash actually are? Maybe they aren't a nullable type. If they are a string, you need to look for string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace instead of null, if they are int, you can see if they are 0 as it is the default value for an integer

Comment: they were numbers and i stored it in string, because of Isolated Storage.

Comment: Ok, then use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace instead of null, as the strings aren't null, they are string.empty by default.

Comment: i edited my answer to show how do you need to test page and hash variables.

Comment: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string)'` Errors

Comment: use String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(page.ToString()) and String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hash.ToString())

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (page == null || hash == null)
```

Instead.  You're query requires both variables to be null.